# Why isn't this code correct for a Goldbach conjecture type output?

Tags: c

I am new to C. I need some assistance in this please.
Based on the prime number and the even positive integer algorithm along with some knowledge of loops and other stuff, I have come up with the following code
for GOLDBACH CONJECTURE.

The compiler says:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
```

```
{
    printf("\t%d\t%d",&t1,&t2);
}
```

Comment: You didn't post your code.  We need to see it in order to help you.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried.

Comment: m trying to get the correct indentation for my code but not able to do it! :( thats why couldnt post the code

Comment: You select the code and click the `{}` button.

Comment: The code you've shown us has nothing at all to do with the Goldbach conjecture. You're just calling `printf` incorrectly.

Comment: The warning tells you the error: %d expects `int`, you're passing `int*`. I suggest you cast or dereference, depending on whether you want the address as an int or the int pointed to. Can't really tell what you need with just that one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

> warning: format `‘%d’` expects argument of type `‘int’`, but argument 2 has type `‘int *’`

**You are sending the arguments of wrong datatype** in the `printf()`.

```
printf("\t%d\t%d",&t1,&t2)
```

Here you are sending `&t1,&t2` which are of the type `int*` as arguments to the `printf()`.But, `%d` format specifier expects an argument of `int` type and that's the reason why you end up with the above warning.

You must instead send `t1,t2` which are of the type `int` as arguments.

```
printf("\t%d\t%d",t1,t2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an integer variable, such as

```
int x;
```

then

```
 &x
```

returns the address of x in memory.

The ampersand (&) is the "address-of" operator.  It returns where things live in memory.

I'm just guessing that you probably used code like this:

```
scanf("%d", &x)
```

to read the value in from a file or input.  While printf uses similar format strings, the arguments are passed by value not address.  So you simply write:

```
printf("%d", x) // not printf("%d", &x);
```

scanf needs the address of the variable passed in order to update the variable in memory from the input.  In other words, it's an output parameter, while for printf it is input.